# How to pass integer variable through intent in android ?

Tags: android, android-intent, integer

I have tried passing variables through Intent before. But it seems that I am missing something that I cant pass the integer variable time. The question has been asked before by others, but I cant get it to work in this situation.

I want to pass the value of the integer variable time to another class which is aftertap.class through intent.

I have this code.

```
public class ingame extends Activity {
private TextView textTimer;
int time = 0;  
Timer t;  
TimerTask task;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ingame);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams();

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

    params.leftMargin = button.getWidth()+ new Random().nextInt(displaymetrics.widthPixels - 2*button.getWidth());
    params.topMargin = button.getHeight()+ new Random().nextInt(displaymetrics.heightPixels - 3*button.getHeight());
    Log.v("widthPixels", ""+ displaymetrics.widthPixels);
    Log.v("heightPixels", ""+ displaymetrics.heightPixels);
    button.setLayoutParams(params);
    startTimer();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              t.cancel();  
              t.purge(); 

            //Starting a new Intent
              Intent thirdscreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), aftertap.class);

                //Sending data to another Activity
                thirdscreen.putExtra("time", time);
                startActivity(thirdscreen);
        }
    });
}
public void startTimer(){  
      t = new Timer();     
      task = new TimerTask() {  

        @Override  
       public void run() {  
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  

          @Override  
         public void run() {
              textTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTimer);
              textTimer.setText(time + "");  
              time = time + 1;  
         }  
        });  
       }  
      };  
      t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1);  
     }  
}
```

Aftertap class:

```
public class aftertap extends Activity{
TextView score;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.aftertap);
    TextView gameover = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gameover);
    score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    // Receiving the Data
   //I do not know how to get the value of the integer variable time. I want to display the value of time in the TextView score
}
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [getIntExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method:

```
int value = i.getIntExtra("time", 0);
```

Change the default value parameter (second parameter) to what you want it to be.

And then display the value

```
score.setText(String.valueOf(value));
```

Comment: how will I display the value of the variable time in the textview score?